# Display a list of images with iterator

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2, iterator

i have a map `Map<String, String> flags;` the values of this map are the names of flags' images. `flags={fr=Flag_fr.jpg, usa=Flag_usa.jpg...}`.
Now i want to diplay the list of flags in my web page using the values ofmy map.

my page jsp looks as below:

```
 <s:iterator value="flags" > 
 <tr>
 <td> 
 <input type="image" src="%{value}">
 </td>
 </tr> 
 </s:iterator>
```

but the button images are not displayed however when i put   the picture is well displayed.

Comment: OGNL expressions (i.e. `%{...}`) work in S2 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what do you mean by "*when i put the picture is well displayed*" but you can try:

```
<input type="image" src='<s:property value="value"/>' value='<s:property value="key" />' />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do as below also

```
<input type="image" src='${value}' value='${key}' />
```